# offset does not work with Count(*) as order by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query with Count(*) as order by with offset fetch next. When I am using different values as offset it is always providing the same resultset.

I tried with some column as order by where the resultset varies and it worked perfectly fine. Can someone help with this.

```
select 
   Id,
   count(*) as "Count" 
from 
   some_table
group by
   "Id"
Order By
   "Count" ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

[Screenshot 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1atMQE_weMzDU-cdoTZod8nRSZEqtnEMb)
[Screenshot 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kBgdpHhw_XKV0_Rd-OM-bVM1tmUlG0p4)

Comment: Are you certain that there are more than 5 groups in your table?

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes there are more that 100 groups in that table. So when we are using Id as Order By with different offset the resultset is varying.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b3a8136d8d77bb02e9d957c62aa092e4).

Comment: you are using `SQL Server 2008` ?

Comment: Sorry we are using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Tim, Probably your count is varying with different groups but in one of my example count is always same and then it is giving same result always. Though I am not sure about that I will post screenshot of that.

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
select Id, count(*) as "Count" 
from some_table
group by "Id"
order by "Count" asc
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

The problem is that you have duplicate values for `count(*)`.  Because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, it has no default ordering.  That poses a problem when sort keys have the same value.

The simple solution is to include `id` in the `order by`:

```
order by "Count" asc, id
```

This makes the sort *stable*, so it is well-defined.

Comment: Hi Gordon, seems valid reason and adding Id would solve the same. But I wanted to have Count only and I think it is not possible. Will try adding some other column. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

here is the My example

1. Create a Table

   ```
   create table t (id int, name varchar(100))
   ```
2. insert data's

   ```
   insert into t values(1,'saravnan')
   insert into t values(1,'kumar')
   insert into t values(1,'Ravi')
   insert into t values(1,'mohan')
   insert into t values(2,'Raju')
   insert into t values(2,'Vikram')
   insert into t values(2,'AA')
   insert into t values(2,'BB')
   insert into t values(2,'CC')
   insert into t values(2,'DD')
   insert into t values(2,'EE')
   insert into t values(3,'Raju')
   insert into t values(3,'Vikram')
   insert into t values(3,'AA')
   insert into t values(4,'BB')
   insert into t values(4,'CC')
   insert into t values(4,'DD')
   insert into t values(4,'EE')
   ```
3. select all data

   ```
   select *from t

       id  name
   1   1   saravnan
   2   1   kumar
   3   1   Ravi
   4   1   mohan
   5   2   Raju
   6   2   Vikram
   7   2   AA
   8   2   BB
   9   2   CC
   10  2   DD
   11  2   EE
   12  3   Raju
   13  3   Vikram
   14  3   AA
   15  4   BB
   16  4   CC
   17  4   DD
   18  4   EE
   ```
4. offset is used for Number of rows skip from start of the table data. it should be number. 
   here my example:

   ```
   select id,count(*) from t group by id order by id offset 1 rows fetch next 3 row only
   ```

   It returns

   ```
       id  count
   1   2   7
   2   3   3
   3   4   4
   ```
5. The fetch next used for number rows to return.
   Solution for your example .

   ```
   --offset 0 returns[enter image description here][1]

   select Id,count(1) as "Count" from t  group by ID Order By "Count" ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY

       Id  Count
   1   3   3
   2   4   4
   3   1   4
   4   2   7

   -- offset 1 returns
   select Id,count(1) as "Count" from t  group by ID Order By "Count" ASC OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY

       Id  Count
   1   4   4
   2   1   4
   3   2   7
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your example but it seems you have different count for every groups, but you can see on my screenshot attached in my case the count for groups are same and I think due the issue is being occured but I am not sure about the exact reason of it.